# Oracle pl/sql: executing dynamic delete within a transaction

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate

I need to delete one or more row from list of tables stored in a table, and commit only if all deletion succeed. 
So I wrote something like this (as part of a bigger procedure):

```sql
BEGIN
    SAVEPOINT sp;

    FOR cur_table IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE_OF_TABLES)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ' || cur_table.TABNAME || ' WHERE ID = :id_bind'
        USING id;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT sp;
END;
```

I know this couldn't work, because of the "execute immediate".

So, what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: what is the issue? are you having an error, a wrong result, ... ?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. I guess "execute immediate" commit itself. Is that wrong?

Comment: it does not commit

Comment: `id` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Also, an anonymous block like this will roll back on failure anyway, so you don't need the savepoint and exception handler.

Comment: Yes, my fault. It's part of a bigger procedure.

Comment: Execute immediate does not automatically commit. It's common misconception, because sometimes you use 'execute immediate' with DDL statements - but then it is DDL part that actually does commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic SQL (Execute Immediate) doesn't commit the transaction. You have to commit explicitly. Your code is fine but it doesn't record/log the errors in case if they occur. 
Log the errors in the exception handler section.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this sounds like a bad idea. Since you have the tables stored in the database, why not just list them out in your procedure? Surely, you're not adding tables that often that this procedure would need to be updated often?

As pointed out in the comments, this will work fine, since `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` does not automatically commit.

Don't forget to add a `RAISE` at the end of your exception block, or you'll never know that an error happened.